# How does Arduino or Raspberry Pi synchronize time using gps?

Tags: launch

I have been looking at time synchronizing using arduino or raspberrypi.
but well still I couldn't find something certain.
does it possible with arduino? 
then how does it have something work? like motor or cctv

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming, not space exploration.

Comment: CCTV, motors, GPS, and computers are widely different things; and it's unclear what is the relation between them in your question.

Comment: @J.Beom, This platform is for space exploration. For your arduino and raspberry related questions, please put the questions on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ .
On these platforms you can get your related answer.

Comment: Short answer is definitely the GPS satellites in space. If your Raspberry Pi or Arduino have a GPS, they can access a very precise timescale while the GPS is connected. You can use programs to synchronize a stable real time clock while you have reception, and if you lose GPS that will be close. Most computers get time from an internet connection to time servers. Those are based on GPS receivers as well, but they have to use some tricks to account for delays over the internet.

Comment: Hi @J.Beom Welcome to Space! If you'd like to ask a question related to GPS and space, this is the right site, but first have a look at other GPS-related questions here to get an idea. The comment about the Raspberry Pi and Arduino Stack Exchange sites is good advice, but there also, have a look at the existing GPS questions before asking something that might be too broad or duplicate.